# Eclipse PyDev not displaying complete output

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to print a long list (over 50,000 elements) with python using eclipse editor. There is a strange problem. When i run the code, i am able to see only half of the output list. 
when i ran this program with the python gui, it runs fine.
are there any settings to be considered in eclipse pydev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know (but don't think so) if there are any settings specific to pydev you should consider. But generally, Eclipse limits the console output. See Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console: by default, "Limit console output" is checked and the limit is set rather low.